# Django pass list to form to create Choices

Tags: django, django-forms, choicefield

I want to create a ChoiceField on a form that has choices from a list passed to it by a view.

```
from django import forms

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    product_choices = []

    def __init__(self, products=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if products:
            print(products)
            choices = enumerate(products)

    product_name = forms.ChoiceField(label='Product', choices=choices)
```

Not sure how to use the init function to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The above will not work, since the `choices` you here define will be taken from a variable named `choices` at construction of the *class*.

You can however generate:

```
from django import forms

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    
    product_name = forms.ChoiceField(label='Product', choices=[])

    def __init__(self, products=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if products:
            self.fields['product_name'].choices = [
                (str(k), v)
                for k, v in enumerate(products))
            ]
```

You thus then construct an `OrderForm` and pass a list (or any iterable of strings) through the `products` parameter, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = OrderForm(products=['product A', 'product B'])
    # ...
    # return some HttpResponse
```

Comment: This form does not seem to return any values? Failing to validate because field returns None

Comment: @Davtho1983: a `Form` does not return values. After `.is_valid()` it will have a dictionary `cleaned_data` that contains the data, you should also pass `request.POST` as data parameter to the form.

Comment: Yeah that's the error I'm getting - object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: Well then your form is simply not valid, so that means you entered invalid data, or you did not pass `request.POST` to the form. A form without passed data is considered invalid.

Comment: Is it because I'm creating the choices as index integers using enumerate when ChoiceField expects to return a string?

Comment: @Davtho1983: ah yes, that is possible. Do you pass the `products`s again when you create a `OrderForm` with the `request.POST` data?

Comment: I do form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, product_titles) before I check if the request is POST, and resetting the form with             form = OrderForm(product_titles) if the request is not POST ?

Comment: @Davtho1983: use named arguments `OrderForm(data=request.POST, products=product_titles)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183235/discussion-between-davtho1983-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: this works for me. As an aside I really wish this answer were a bit more popular because, of all my search on SO, this one seems to be the most straightforward in passing arguments to a form via views