# django form 'str' object has no attribute 'id' when passing a list of choices

Tags: django

I am creating a form where the view passes a list to the form and this list is used to create choices.  The choices seems to be created correctly, but I get an error `'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

I first learned how to pass the list using this: [Django pass list to form to create Choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177528/)

**models.py**

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    """Each time a new score is added we create a grade object to track history of grades"""

    score = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=PROFSCALE, blank=True, default=INCOMPLETE)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(
        Assessment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    objective = models.ForeignKey(
        Objective, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cblock = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    time_created = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=timezone.now)
        
class Objective(models.Model):
    """The gradebook is graded agains learning objectives"""
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objective_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objective_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objective_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class SingleGradeForm(forms.Form):
    """ form for adding in one single grade for a student. """
    SCORE_CHOICES = (
        ("IN", "I"),
        ("BE", "BEG"),
        ("DV", "DEV"),
        ("AP", "APP"),
        ("EX", "EXT"),
    )
    score = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES)
    objective = forms.ChoiceField(label='Learning Objectives', choices=[])
    time_created = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'date'}), label='Assessment Date')

    # from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177528/
    def __init__(self, objs=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SingleGradeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if objs:
            self.fields['objective'].choices = [
                (o.id, o.objective_name)
                for o in objs
            ]

        print(self.fields['objective'].choices)
```

**views.py**

```
def addsinglegrade(request, classroom_id, student_id):
    c = Classroom.objects.get(id=classroom_id)
    s = Student.objects.get(id=student_id)
    course = Course.objects.get(classroom=classroom_id)
    objective_list = Objective.objects.all().filter(course=course)
    print(objective_list)
    form = SingleGradeForm(objs=objective_list)
    context = {'student': s}
    context['classroom'] = c

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SingleGradeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            new_grade = form.save(commit=False)
            # save the course that the objective belongs to
            new_grade.student = s
            new_grade.cblock = c
            new_grade.objective = objective
            new_grade.score = score
            new_grade.time_created = time_created
            new_grade.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            return redirect('gradebook:studentgradebook', student_id, classroom_id)

        else:
            print("not valid")
            #context['form'] = form
            return render(request, "gradebook/grade_single_form.html", context)

    else:
        form = SingleGradeForm(objs=objective_list)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "gradebook/grade_single_form.html", context)
```

I think the objective choices is being created correctly because with `print(self.fields['objective'].choices)` in the form, I get this: `[('1', 'frac.1'), ('2', 'frac.2'), ('3', 'frac.3'), ('6', 'frac.4')]`, which is a correct list of tuples of the objectives' id and name.

I have also tried `(str(o.id), o.objective_name)` but I got the same error on this line

Here is the complete error trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/gradebook/addsinglegrade/1/44/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_select2',
 'crispy_forms',
 'gradebook',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\gradebook-6RQSg7dk\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\.virtualenvs\gradebook-6RQSg7dk\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\OneDrive\django\gradebook\gradebook\views.py", line 497, in addsinglegrade
    form = SingleGradeForm(request.POST)
  File "C:\Users\Doug\OneDrive\django\gradebook\gradebook\forms.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.fields['objective'].choices = [
  File "C:\Users\Doug\OneDrive\django\gradebook\gradebook\forms.py", line 156, in <listcomp>
    (str(o.id), o.objective_name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /gradebook/addsinglegrade/1/44/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Could you give the complete error trace please

Comment: Original post edited to include the complete error trace.

Comment: Try to change `form = SingleGradeForm(request.POST)` to `form = SingleGradeForm(data=request.POST)`